# iOS Simulator Iphone- 4 inch Weird Display Size

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I just updated to Xcode 5 and when I run the simulator with Iphone- 4 inch It cuts off my homescreen image which is exactly 1136 x 640. I am using cocos2d.

The screen clearly does not have the same proportions as the iphone 5. What is going on?

[image: picture]

Comment: Is that cocos2d you are using?

Comment: what version are u using ?

Comment: Same issue for me. Hopefully someone can answer